# Debian Sid / GCC5 transition : is running apt-get upgrade safe ?

Tags: debian

I know `apt-get dist-upgrade` is expected to break things during the [GCC5 transition](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2015/08/msg00000.html), but is `apt-get upgrade` safe to execute ?

Comment: Can you expand upon your definition of "safe" so there is a common understanding?

Comment: "Safe" would mean "does not break the distro" I think.

Comment: It would help to know which distribution you're tracking; stable, testing or unstable (sid)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the announcement sent to visitors inquiring about this on the official #debian-next IRC channel on the OFTC network.

> One of the biggest transitions ever undertaken in Debian: new versions
>   of libstdc++/gcc require over 3000 source packages to be recompiled. 
>   Don't expect packages in sid to be installable; use testing instead.
>   https://release.debian.org/transitions/html/libstdc++6.html (and if
>   you didn't already know this, ask yourself if you should be using
>   sid).